# Google App Engine Blobstore API asks for login while serving uploaded file

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I want to serve the file uploaded via blobstore to everyone who views the website without asking for login. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you serving it now? Sounds like the handler serving the blob requires login (possibly via `login: required` in the `app.yaml` config file?). You'd need to show the relevant handler section in your `app.yaml` file and/or app code.

Comment: It was my mistake, I had kept login: required in app.yaml. Solved it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Image API for this. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService#getServingUrl-com.google.appengine.api.images.ServingUrlOptions-).

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the handler serving the blob doesn't have the `login: required` flag in the `app.yaml` config file.